# How to make links in GMail emails open in a new Chrome browser tab

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

For many years, it was standard behavior in my experience that links in Gmail emails opened in a new Chrome browser tab.

Now such links suddenly open inside the GMail tab, which even is a pinned tab in Google Chrome.

How to get the "open in new tab" behavior back?

Note that I don't want to make every link everywhere to open in a new tab -- only links within Gmail (or coming from a pinned tab, for that matter).

Comment: If you are you still facing this problem please add more details like operative name and version, chrome version, if this happens in guest an incognito mode too.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that I had a conflicting add-on that was causing this.